# optimization for processing big data in pyspark

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Not a question->need a suggestion

I am operating on 20gb+6gb=26Gb csv file with 1+3 (1-master, 3-slave (each of 16 gb RAM).

This is how I am doing my ops

```
df = spark.read.csv() #20gb
df1 = spark.read.csv() #6gb
df_merged= df.join(df1,'name','left') ###merging 
df_merged.persists(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) ##if i do MEMORY_ONLY will I gain more performance?????
print('No. of records found: ',df_merged.count())  ##just ensure persist by calling an action
df_merged.registerTempTable('table_satya')
query_list= [query1,query2,query3]  ###sql query string to be fired
city_list = [city1, city2,city3...total 8 cities]
file_index=0 ###will create files based on increasing index
for query_str in query_list:
   result = spark.sql(query_str) #ex: select * from table_satya where date >= '2016-01-01'
   #result.persist()  ###willit increase performance
   for city in city_list:
        df_city = result.where(result.city_name==city)
        #store as csv file(pandas style single file)
        df_city.collect().toPandas().to_csv('file_'+str(file_index)+'.csv',index=False)
        file_index += 1

df_merged.unpersist()  ###do I even need to do it or Spark can handle it internally
```

Currently it is taking a huge time.

```
#persist(On count())-34 mins.
#each result(on firing each sql query)-around (2*8=16min toPandas() Op)
#          #for each toPandas().to_csv() - around 2 min each
#for 3 query 16*3= 48min
#total 34+48 = 82 min  ###Need optimization seriously
```

So can anybody suggest how can i optimize the above process for a better performance(Time and Memory both.)

Why I am worried is : I was doing the above on Python-Pandas platform (64Gb single machine with serialized pickle data) and I was able to do that in 8- 12mins. As my data-volume seems growing, so need to adopt a technology like spark.

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Anytime you serialize to disk you incur huge I/O penalties.  The power of Spark is to only use memory to keep things fast.  You need to persist to memory, and make sure you have enough memory to handle the data.  You also want to make sure you've configured your env correctly...Transparent Huge Pages should be off and swappiness set to 0 or 1.

Comment: Does your raw data have only the eight cities you are looking for or does it have many more?

Comment: Is this correct?  `result.where('city_name'==city)`.  That would seem to be asking for `result.where(False)`.  Did you mean something like `result.where("city_name='%s'" % city)` ?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski-No, I  have many more cities(90 appx.). And yes result.where(result.city_name==city). I have corrected it.

Comment: @tadamhicks- How can I set "Transparent Huge Pages should be off and swappiness set to 0 or 1". what are the variables to do so. Plz, help. And by your comment do you mean , if I do df_merged.persists(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY) , will I get performance gain???

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is cutting the source data down to size.  You mention that your source data has 90 cities, but you are only interested in 8 of them.  Filter out the cities you don't want and keep the ones you do want in separate csv files:

```
import itertools
import csv

city_list = [city1, city2,city3...total 8 cities]

with open('f1.csv', 'rb') as f1, open('f2.csv', 'rb') as f2:
    r1, r2 = csv.reader(f1), csv.reader(f2)
    header = next(r1)
    next(r2) # discard headers in second file
    city_col = header.index('city_name')
    city_files = []
    city_writers = {}
    try:
    for city in city_list:
            f = open(city+'.csv', 'wb')
            city_files.append(f)
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(header)
            city_writers[city] = writer
        for row in itertools.chain(r1, r2):
            city_name = row[city_col]
            if city_name in city_writers:
                city_writers[city_name].writerow(row)
    finally:
        for f in city_files:
            f.close()
```

After this iterate over each city, creating a DataFrame for the city, then in a nested loop run your three queries.  Each DataFrame should have no problem fitting in memory and the queries should run quickly since they are running over a much smaller data set.